# Can I run .odex file on dalvikvm?

Tags: dalvik, odex, dalvik-cache

As I can run a Dex file on dalvikvm through a terminal emulator (I'm using termux or adb shell
`/system/bin/dalvikvm -cp /path/to/classes.dex classname`

Which runs successfully and I noticed it generated a directory `oat` which contains `oat/arm64/classes.odex and classes.vdex` file.  odex is faster than Dex so can I run it directly every time without recompiling dex to odex?